# Implementing copy, cut and paste

Tags: vb.net, graphics, copy, paste, cut

I want to implement copy, cut and paste in my drawing program (copy part of an image that is selected)

I don't know how to start

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

to copy: take the selected rectangle, create a new image of that size, take a copy of the current image and place it on the new rectangle, offset by the topleft of the selected rectangle

Answer (score 1):

in short there are two ways exists

1) your own clipboard
2) system-wide clipboard

in second case use must use standard format for storing your data. read MSDN for more information about windows clipboard

or you can maintain two clipboards - own and system. then in *your* clipboard you can store specific information for your application and in system cliboard just image

Answer (score 1):

Here are some global points that will drasticly speed up your issues that you'll be facing.

Try to search for reversible line / rubberband. to make selections in the picture.
Try to search for LockBits in VB .NET , to create a fast way of reading and writing pixels.
Try to learn background thread , and report progress. For per pixel operations that take a long time.
Try to make a MDI. With enough status bars to report the status.
Try to serialize to xml/binary when saving a project-file to disk (like a psd for example).
This could also be handy , for creating a undo function.

Answer (score 1):

see this one...

http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/javascript-copy-selected-text-box-select-all-highlight-text-form-copy-paste-t706.html

but for firefox its not working. am also searching for similar one. will post if i get more.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Use the system-wide clipboard**, just in case the user copy in one instance on your app and paste in another, or if the user close the window and re-open it, he can paste back the data.
2. **Inherit all the shapes** of the program from a base class that implements the copy & paste.
3. **For copy** (or cut), serialize the object and place it in the system clipboard.
4. **For paste**, read the system clipboard and try to de-serialize back to a shape object (if the cast fails, the clipboard content was not an object of your app)
5. **Move the position** of the pasted shape slightly to the left and bottom (to let the user know that there is a new shape in the drawing)